# Telethon calls and video broadcasts

Tags: api, telegram, telethon

Can i make calls and broadcasts using telethon or other python libraries?
I found https://mdqinc.com/blog/2018/08/telegram-voip-calls-using-python/
but this is only an experimental version.

Comment: https://github.com/MarshalX/tgcalls or https://github.com/pytgcalls/pytgcalls. 2 different libraries that do what you want but both of them do it in different ways

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.